# Grails/MongoDB Morphia Plugin:

Tags: mongodb, grails, morphia

I am trying to use Mongodb with a Grails app through the Mongodb Morphia Plugin (v.0.7.8). I have annotated a domain-class (which is *not* inside of the grails-app/mongo folder) with the com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Entity Annotation:

```
import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Entity

@Entity("Question")
class Question {
    Integer order
    String question
}
```

now I am trying to save a new entity into the database in a controller:

```
def index() {
    def q = new Question()
}
q.save()
```

but that raises a HTTP 500 error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
Method on class [Question] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
```

what am I doing wrong?

edit:

i moved my domain classes to grails-app/mongo and removed the @Entity annotation. Now the error disappeared, but the database is still empty?

edit2:

now I get:

```
URI
/Survey/survey/index
Class
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
Message
survey.Survey.<init>()
```

either this plugin is severely bugged or it is not as easy to set up as the quickstart micro example suggests it to be. again: what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a user guide on how to use that plugin http://jkuehn.github.com/gorm-mongodb/guide/2.%20Quickstart.html

A sample application is available here https://github.com/jkuehn/gorm-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Here are the things you could do:

First:
If you came from GORM MongoDB like me, try to check your DataSource.groovy. And replace mongo {} with mongodb{} so the mongodb-morphia would work.

Second:
Edit your class, and do this:

```
import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Entity
@Entity
class Question {
   ///your code...
}
```

I noticed that it is not necessary to add @Entity('Question') unless you are extending from other object.

**Edits:**
Okay, after I saw your error message and your code, I just realized something, you were calling q.save() outside of the Controller action method.

This was your code:

```
def index() {
    def q = new Question()
}
q.save()
```

Please try:

```
def index() {
    def q = new Question()
    q.save()
}
```